# XSLT template match for CSV transform

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I'm using the following XSL to transform XML to CSV, based on an earlier SO query.

XML:

```
<Rows>
<Row>
<LoanNumber>123456</LoanNumber>
<DateReceived>2015-04-10</DateReceived>
<DateClosed>2015-04-10</DateClosed>
</Row>
<Row>
<LoanNumber>9988776</LoanNumber>
<DateReceived>2015-04-10</DateReceived>
<DateClosed/>
</Row>
</Rows>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/*/child::*">
<xsl:for-each select="child::*">
<xsl:if test="position() = 1"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>,OPEN,</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="position() != 1 and position() != last()"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>,</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="position()  = last()"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/><xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'd like to be able to output the following CSV for the above rows

```
123456, CLOSED, 2015-04-10, 2015-04-10
9988776, OPEN, 2015-04-10,
```

I'd assumed I could achieve this by having 2 templates, one outputting the text OPEN, where the `<DateClosed>` element is null and one outputting the text CLOSED where it is not.

However I don't understand the template match that's been used well enough to be able to figure out how to do this. Could this requirement be met in one template even?

Comment: Is your expected output definitely correct? Shouldn't the row for 123456 be CLOSED?

Comment: You are right, thanks. Editted to fix.

Comment: @BenL Please do not edit OP's code - you don't know what it looks like.

Comment: @BenL suggested the edit to me, and I approved it assuming the edit was just indentation.

Comment: Most of time indentation does not matter, but sometimes it can make a difference. It's best not to touch the original code (especially after an answer relying on the original code has been posted).

Comment: Apologies. I thought it would be OK to indent for readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output does not match your input. Assuming you want the result to show 
LoanNumber, Status, DateReceived, DateClosed I would suggest you try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>

<xsl:template match="/Rows">
    <xsl:for-each select="Row">
        <xsl:value-of select="LoanNumber"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string(DateClosed)">CLOSED,</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>OPEN,</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:value-of select="DateReceived"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="DateClosed"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks - I've editted the output to match, will give this a go.